# How to stop apostrophes around a string appearing when the string is appended to a list - Python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, multidimensional-array

When I run this piece of code:

```
MasterPots = []
PotTitle = "Oranges"
BeforePT = "["
AfterPT = ", 0]"
TempString = BeforePT + PotTitle + AfterPT
MasterPots.append(TempString)
print (MasterPots)
```

I expect the result of:

```
[[Oranges, 0]]
```

However, I keep getting the result of:

```
['[Oranges, 0]']
```

How do I stop Python 3 from putting the apostrophe around the string when it is appended to the array?

For reference:

-The value of PotTitle is set by a function however for example purposes I have set it to "Oranges"

-When I run:

```
print(TempString)
```

I get:

```
[Oranges, 0]
```

Comment: You're making a string "[Oranges, 0]", then appending it to a list.

Comment: You can't get a result of `[[Oranges, 0]]`. Did you want `[['Oranges', 0]]`?

Comment: Yes when you print(TempString) it will give [Oranges, 0], because it's printing the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to parse the string if you **must** keep the item that you are adding to the list a string representation before you are adding it.

This turns the string representation of the list into an actual list.

You can do this by doing:

```
import ast
MasterPots.append(ast.literal_eval(TempString))
```

The other solution is to have it as a list in the first place and append it to the list:

```
MasterPots.append([PotTitle, 0])
```

Note that you are probably experiencing an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I get an exception with this code: `ValueError: malformed node or string`

Comment: @quamrana this is because Orange is not a string within your list so you have to do `"['Orange', 1]"`

Comment: I agree with the `XY Problem`, but none of your code makes sense. Should your last line be: `MasterPots.append([PotTitle,0])`?

Comment: @StephenMoss its unclear what exactly you are trying to accomplish. If you just want to change the title of the potion that is added the PotTitle without any of the string stuff will accomplish what you want.

Comment: @quamrana Yeah, that's right. I was looking at it from the wrong perspective.

Answer (score 1):

```
MasterPots = []
TempString = ["Oranges",0]
MasterPots.append(TempString)
print (MasterPots)
```

Output

```
[['Oranges', 0]]
```

Is this more of what you are interested in?

```
Oranges = "Something not Oranges"
Num_Oranges = 0

MasterPots = []
TempString = [Oranges, Num_Oranges]
MasterPots.append(TempString)
print (MasterPots)
print(TempString)
```

Output:

```
[['Something not Oranges', 0]]
['Something not Oranges', 0]
```

Comment: Erm, the point was to have no speech marks around Oranges and to have it so Oranges can change (PotTitle is a variable that is used in a loop and changes with each iteration).

Comment: Oranges is a string, the only other thing it can be is a variable. If it is a string then python will have quotations around it indicating it is a string, if it is a variable it will print the value stored in the variable.

Comment: @StephenMoss I'm still sure you can't get your desired result.

Comment: Maybe a little more insight on where the Oranges (string or variable?) is coming from?